# how to fix files wont open on Github

Tags: git, github

i have pushed my project from Git to Github and the src directory wont open in github although other directory like images are opening fine

i tried to redo the push command but it;s the same 
also i tried git add src/. but it sayed nothing to commit, working tree clean

what i have typed :

```
git init 
git add . && git commit . -m "initial commit"
git remote origin -v
git push origin master
```

[image: img]

[my github repo](https://github.com/AmineMahiddine/my_website)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "won't open"? Can you share the error you're getting?

Comment: see https://github.com/AmineMahiddine/my_website  the src file

Answer (score 1):

`src` isn't a file, it's an empty directory. Once you add a file in it, commit it and push that commit, you'll be able to navigate to it from the GitHub UI.

Comment: Git doesn't store empty directories, so `src` is therefore a gitlink entry: half a submodule.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is fixed :
delete the ./src file from the mother directory 
recopie it again 
type then:

```
git add . && git commit . -m "comment"

git fetch https://github.com/username/repo_name

git pull https://github.com/username/repo_name

git push origin master
```